# Compiz setting to maximize application window without integrating in global menu

Tags: 11.04, compiz

I have mainly problem with applications under Wine. Global menu integration is problematic most of the time: either there is empty (transparent) line block between global menu and application window or if there is not such "hole", application does not respond to mouse pointer coordinates (like vertical position is shifted some -20-30px)

I don't know where to search in all Compiz settings, but I would like to set some keyboard shortcut which will trigger command to "maximise" application windows on desktop space without integrating in global menu.
I'm almost sure there is such setting, but couldn't find it

---

I found action "Fill Screen" in Edges tab from Grid settings, but can't find how to associate it to keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps alt+ctrl+numpad5 does what you want? It resizes a window to fit the screen, but without maximizing it.